# Phoenix + Elixir: outdated static file is served

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a sitemap file that is located in `priv/static/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml`

```
▾ priv/
  ▸ gettext/
  ▸ repo/
  ▾ static/
    ▸ assets/
    ▸ images/
    ▾ sitemaps/
        sitemap.xml
        sitemap1.xml   // <=================
      favicon.ico
      robots.txt
```

In addition, I have added the `sitemaps` folder to `static_paths` in `lib/MyApp.ex`

```
  def static_paths, do: ~w(assets fonts images favicon.ico robots.txt sitemaps)
```

However, it continues to serve an outdated version of my sitemap when I visit `https://www.myapp.com/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml` even after multiple deploys / restarts. I even sshed into the server and opened up the file to confirm that the file was different from the one being served.

Am I missing a step? Or is there another way of serving static files?

Comment: What `wget https://www.myapp.com/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml` yields?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin the outdated version is returned

Comment: I wonder if it could be gigalixir? I could always make a controller + action for it if that prevents caching

Comment: I think I figured it out: My worker is creating a file in `priv/static/sitemaps`, and it looks like it's saving the file in a different location from the release's folder

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the file to a known location, and put a new [`Plug.Static`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html) call in your `Endpoint`:

```elixir
plug Plug.Static, from: "my/custom/relative/dir"
```

---

If your worker is only specifying the relative `priv` directory, it is probably saving to a different directory than the one the release uses. Releases use the application's directory inside the release, rather than the working directory. You can ensure you save to the application's directory by using [`Application.app_dir/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#app_dir/1):

```elixir
:myapp
|> Application.app_dir()
|> Path.join("priv/static/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml")
|> File.write!(xml)
```

However, this is not a good idea because you're generating dynamic content at runtime, and injecting it into what is supposed to be a pre-compiled release, so I think the extra `plug Plug.Static` suggestion above is better. Or generate the content at compile-time, and include it in the release.